# javascript: Could not add two text inputs

Tags: javascript

This does not add the numbers instead gives NaN

```
  <html>
        <body>
            <script>
                function checkit()
                {
                    x = document.getElementById("a");
                    x1 = parseInt(x);
                    y = document.getElementById("b");
                    y1 = parseInt(y);
                    alert("Answer is" + (x1 + y1));
                }

            </script>

            <input type="text" id="a">
            <input type="text" id="b">
            <input type="button" onclick="checkit()">

        </body>
    </html>
```

Even tried document.getElementById("a").value;
Still gives NaN

Comment: Why would you expect to be able to parse an element into a number?

Comment: `x = document.getElementById("a").value;`

Comment: You need to use `value` property of element and always use `parseInt(x, 10)` with radix

Comment: Beware that your code is falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) because you don't declare your variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementById` returns the HTML element (an input, in your case), not its value. Try this instead:

```
x = document.getElementById("a").value;
```

Comment: It wasn't working at first Chrome but now its working.
Thanks anyways